# Why is the function in my hooks.py file not being called? django-paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm following this tutorial: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html

Go to step 5. That's where I'm at. Here's my code:

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received, invalid_ipn_received
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings

from engine.models import Invoice
from engine.models import PaypalError

if settings.PAYPAL_TEST:
    business_email = "redacted"
else:
    business_email = "redacted"


def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender

    invoice_id = ipn_obj.invoice
    invoice = Invoice.objects.get(inv_id=invoice_id)
    amount = invoice.price
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # WARNING !
        # Check that the receiver email is the same we previously
        # set on the `business` field. (The user could tamper with
        # that fields on the payment form before it goes to PayPal)
        if ipn_obj.receiver_email != business_email:
            # Not a valid payment
            return

        # ALSO: for the same reason, you need to check the amount
        # received, `custom` etc. are all what you expect or what
        # is allowed.

        if ipn_obj.mc_gross == amount and ipn_obj.mc_currency == 'USD':

            invoice.is_paid = True
            invoice.date_paid = datetime.now()
            invoice.save()
    else:
        pass

def invalid_ipn(sender, **kwargs):
    inv_id = sender.invoice
    invoice = Invoice.objects.get(inv_id=inv_id)
    err = PayPalError.objects.create(invoice=invoice)

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
invalid_ipn_received.connect(invalid_ipn)
```

I know it's not being called because the `is_paid` field of each invoice never gets set to `True` after paying (in the Paypal sandbox). Can anyone lend some insight? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it's not being called because the is_paid field of each invoice never gets set to True after paying

That doesn't imply it's not being called. It may not be being called, or it may not be passing all the checks in that code before marking something as paid.

To see whether IPN messages are being delivered by PayPal, review the receiver account's IPN history -- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history for sandbox mode.

If the IPNs are being sent and received correctly, you'll need to debug the code to determine what prevents it from reaching the point of marking something as paid. Add logging output to your code.